# Hotels in Barcelona for People Aged 17?

Tags: hotels, barcelona, age-limits

I wanted to know if there are hotels in Barcelona that allow people over 16 to check in (under 18).

Comment: No, it's illegal

Comment: Are you checking in alone, or with others who are older than 18? (parents or friends, for exmaple)

Comment: @MikkaRin no it's not, there's just restrictions.

Comment: I would expand this question to hotels in Barcelona which don't check for an ID. No ID = no age limit.

Comment: @pnuts: you can get a *debit* card at the age of 15, as long as your parents give you a written permission (at least in Europe)

Comment: @pnuts it's illegal because contract between 16 years old and hotel has no legal power, that's why hotels prefer not to host youth under 18.

Answer (score 5):

Well, some may have their own policies.  For example, some require you to book or check in with a credit card - and you have to be 18 to own one of those.

However, I have found a couple of hostels that would accept this, with some restrictions, if you would consider that. Many hostels, especially if you book a private room, work just like budget hotels, albeit often with shared bathrooms and kitchens.

For example, the [Barcelona Urbany Hostel](http://www.urbanyhostels.com/urbany-barcelona/general-faqs) states in their FAQ:

> If the person under 18 travels with an adult, they can stay in the
>   hostel but only in a private room (never a shared dorm). If the person
>   under 18 travels alone or with another person under 18, we’ll ask for
>   an Authorization document signed by an adult relative or legal tutor,
>   and they will be allowed to stay in the hostel but only in a private
>   room (never a shared dorm).

The [Mediterranean Youth Hostel](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Mediterranean-Youth-Hostel/Barcelona/6053) says:

> No guests under 16.

So 17 year olds would be allowed there.  However, it doesn't mention whether or not they can travel alone - it'd be worth checking if that's what you're planning on doing.  Regardless, a letter from your parents or teacher or guardian will always help smooth things over.

Comment: @pnuts yeah, that's why I mentioned the guardian - as they've not specified.  If they say they want to  book it on their own completely, then yeah, the second hostel would appear to work, and it'd be a good idea to have a letter.
Regardless I'd be contacting the hostel/hotel before booking to make sure.

Comment: @MarkMayo you can get a debit card at the age of 15 (at least in Europe), as long as you have written permission from your parents

Comment: @JonathanReez, today I learned! Of course not every hotel will accept debit cards :/

Comment: @MarkMayo: I've never seen a hotel that specifically asked for a debit card (maybe it's a thing with 5-star hotels?)

Comment: @JonathanReez Hotels will accept a debit card instead of a credit card as long as you are happy to hold a large charge on the card. Hostels usually just ask for cash up front.